# i want to use the joystick on RPI SenseHat as input in my java based game

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

I recently made a 2-d puzzle game using java and I was wondering if it were possible to use the joystick on my RPI SenseHat to move the character in the game. I am quite new to java programming and I have no idea how to do this.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Most controllers/joystick are just keyboards with less keys. Have you tried just plugging it in and check which keys are triggered when you move the stick?

Comment: I'll sure give that a try.